# How to group and reference with lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

In this example:

```
("Talking with Bengt Holmstrom 1" "#44")
("Chapter 1 What is Economics? 3" "#46")
```

, which is matched by regex `^(?!.*(Chapter|Part)).*\n\("Chapter.*\n`, I would like to 
have two groups `("Talking with Bengt Holmstrom 1" "#44")` and `("Chapter 1 What is Economics? 3" "#46")`.

To group, the above regex is modified to be`^((?!.*(Chapter|Part)).*)\n(\("Chapter.*)\n`. I want to refer to the two groups, but using `\1` and `\2` as their references as in `\1\2` doesn't work. I was wondering if anything is wrong?

BTW, I am using gedit regex plugin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refer to them as \1 and \3.

Just count the opening ( as you go from left to right. 1) is `((?!.*(Chapter|Part)).*)`, so the first line. 2) is `(Chapter|Part)` 3) is `("Chapter.*)`, so the second line starting with "Chapter.

Note that the ( that is the beginning of the lookahead is not counted.

Comment: Thanks! Why is it? What are all the groups? Why doesn't `\2` work?